# Creating multi-threading in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading

I have a Linux computer and want to do the following (two independent actions/processes if possible):

1. Run a series of CLI commands every x minutes towards a remote computer to see if a file exists there. If it does, I want to start downloading this file to one of my directories. The files could be big and there might be many remote computers, so ideally I should treat each connection as an own process.
2. Check to see if a new file has arrived in my file system. If it has, I want to go through this file, analyze the content with some algoritms and then store the result in a database that I have installed. Then delete the file that was analyzed.

Any recommendations on how to do this the "best" and most reliable way? Scripting? Java/C/etc? Multi threading or just a single process that is looping through the content? The result should be something that should run for months without stopping.

Any suggestions and/or sample code very welcome!

Thanks!
Z

Answer (score 0):

For #1, you can use crantab(http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) to run your script.

I think you can use Shell, Python, Ruby to complete your tasks

Answer (score 0):

for downloading you can use a mix of something like that script (not tested and incomplete):

---

```
function download_and_analyze(link){
    Z=mktemp
    cd $Z
    wget -c -t0 -q -C $link 
    # analyze algorithm here
    cd /tmp
    rm -rf $Z
 }

for A in $REMOTEFILE; do 
      download_and_analyze($A) &
done
```

---

this is just a scratch to you implement it as a shell script. Realiability is guaranteed by wget.

you also can use rsync if it's on another computer acessible by ssh.

cheers